# How to sort a GridView in groups?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I've got a GridView which reads in data from a DataTable.

Every couple of rows, is a different category. When the user clicks on a column for sorting, I would like to sort the results depending on each category? I.e. not just sorting all records, but all records of each categroy.

How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:  http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html  It actually wraps a ListView but it may work for you and it has built in grouping